# Manejo de interrupciones con botones en un reloj

Tags: c++, arduino

He implementado interrupciones en 2 botones en un reloj de formato de 24 horas realizado en Arduino el cual se muestra en un LCD, esto con la finalidad de garantizar el funcionamiento de dicho botones los cuales no funcionan correctamente sin las ya mencionadas interrupciones.

Ahora, el problema que que estoy enfrentando es relacionado a los rebotes mecánicos. Usualmente utilizaría un Do-While y un delay para manejar los rebotes mecánicos y asegurar una correcta lectura de valores cuando el botón es presionado, pero dado a que estoy utilizando interrupciones esto ya no es conveniente. ¿Cómo puedo asegurar que los valores al presionar los botones sean los correctos?
Adicionalmente también he encontrado otro problema, y es que cada que los valores de horas o minuto llegan a múltiplos de 10, el programa tiende a desaparecer por un instante. ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar esto?

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
int su=0;
int sd=0;
volatile int mu=0;
volatile int md=0;
volatile int hu=0;
volatile int hd=0;
int pm=2;
int ph=3;



void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 pinMode(pm, INPUT);
 pinMode(ph, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pm),handleInterrupt,FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ph),handleInterrupt1,FALLING);



 
}

void loop() {

    su++;
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(su);
    lcd.setCursor(7,0);
    lcd.print(sd);

  if(su==10)
  {
    su=0;
    sd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(sd==6 && su==0)
  {
    su=0;
    sd=0;
    mu++;
    lcd.clear();

  }
  if(mu==10)
  {
    mu=0;
    md++;
    lcd.clear();

  }
  if(md==6 && mu==0)
  {
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    hu++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hu==10)
  {
    hu=0;
    hd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hd==2 && hu==4)
  {
    hd=0;
    hu=0;
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    sd=0;
    su=0;
    lcd.clear();
  }

    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print(hd);
    lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print(hu);
    lcd.setCursor(3,0);
    lcd.print(":");

    lcd.setCursor(4,0);
    lcd.print(md);
    lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    lcd.print(mu);
    lcd.setCursor(6,0);
    lcd.print(":");

    lcd.setCursor(7,0);
    lcd.print(sd);
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(su);

}

void handleInterrupt(){
  mu++;
  if(mu==10)
  {
    mu=0;
    md++;
    lcd.clear();

  }
  if(md==6 && mu==0)
  {
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    hu++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hu==10)
  {
    hu=0;
    hd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hd==2 && hu==4)
  {
    hd=0;
    hu=0;
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    sd=0;
    su=0;
    lcd.clear();
  }

}

void handleInterrupt1(){
  hu++;
  if(hu==10)
  {
    hu=0;
    hd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hd==2 && hu==4)
  {
    hd=0;
    hu=0;
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    sd=0;
    su=0;
    lcd.clear();
  }

}
```

Comment: No entendí, puedes ser más claro? Qué sería responder correctamente? A lo mejor no necesitas interrupciones. La función `delay` bloquea la ejecución hasta que pasa el tiempo estipulado. Qué tal si usas `millis()` para averiguar el tiempo transcurrido y haces que lo que deba pasar cada x tiempo ocurra por ejemplo, cuando millis() % 1000 == 0 se cumpla? En este caso ocurriría cada 1 segundo. Por cierto, si utilizas interrupciones, no puedes usar `delay` ni ningún código que dure demasiado https://forum.arduino.cc/t/delay-and-interrupts/405046

Comment: Claro, empecemos con que el programa base es un reloj de 24 horas al cual se lo debe de igualar con 2 botones, uno para minutos y otro para segundos. Ahora la forma en la que el reloj esta hecho es bastante rustica, simplemente un contador que incrementa en el loop para luego tener una pausa de 1 segundo y así crear la ilusión de segundos incrementándose. Ahora, el problema surge debido a ese mismo Delay de un segundo, debido a que si presionas un botón este muchas veces no responde, no hace el incremento.

Comment: Intento implementar interrupciones para solucionar este inconveniente, necesito que los segundos sigan incrementándose sin alteración independientemente si se presiona un pulsador

Comment: ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: ¿Entonces el reloj debe avanzar solo? ¿Cuál es el propósito de los botones?

Comment: Los botones son para modificar los valores. Un botón para modificar las horas y otro botón para modificar los minutos. En cualquier de estos casos solo debe de bastar con presionar una vez cualquiera de los 2 botones para modificar su valor correspondiente, y estas acciones no debe interrumpir el paso de los segundos.

Comment: El reloj es un reloj de 24 horas, mientras este conectado este avanzara como un reloj normal que te indica la hora

Comment: Ah, ya entendí. El reloj funciona siempre y usas los botones para poner el reloj en hora.

Comment: Exacto, ahora el inconveniente que se presenta es que el programa no siempre detecta cuando presiono los botones. Debo de mantener presionado un botón por un tiempo para ver un cambio. He intentado de otros enfoques pero no a funcionado, ya que terminan afectando el conteo de los segundos.

Comment: Me dijeron que con interrupciones podría interrumpir el programa principal en cualquier momento y ejecutar un subprograma que realice la modificación de los minutos y horas cuando los respectivos botones sean pulsados de manera adecuada

Comment: Si. El detalle es que el código que se ejecuta en las interrupciones debe ser breve y nada de usar `delay`. En los links que te dejé lo explica. https://proyectosconarduino.com/curso/interrupciones-arduino-attachinterrupt/?expand_article=1 y https://forum.arduino.cc/t/delay-and-interrupts/405046

Answer (score 0):

`delay` bloquea la ejecución del programa y no permite hacer otra cosa mientras pasa el tiempo indicado. Así que no puedes usar `delay` en tu programa.

Se me ocurre que utilices la función [`millis`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/es/language/functions/time/millis/), para obtener una referencia de tiempo y con un `if` hacer algo solo si pasó un segundo. Por ejemplo:

```
typedef unsigned long tiempo;

tiempo ultima_vez;
const tiempo un_segundo = 1000;

int segundos = 0, minutos = 0, horas = 0;

void tick(){
    segundos++;
    if (segundos < 60) return;

    minutos++;
    segundos = 0;
    if (minutos < 60) return;

    horas++;
    minutos = 0;
    if (horas < 24) return;

    horas = 0;
}

// Es para poner el reloj en hora. Al llegar a 60 no aumenta las horas.
void pasar_un_minuto(){
    minutos = (minutos + 1) % 60;
}

// También es para poner el reloj en hora.
void pasar_una_hora(){
    horas = (horas + 1) % 24;
}

void setup(){
    ultima_vez = millis();
}

bool tick_dado = false;

void loop(){
    tiempo ahora = millis();
    tiempo transcurrido = ahora - ultima_vez;

    if (transcurrido >= un_segundo){
        // Probablemente el procesador se ejecute varias veces en un
        // milisegundo, pero solo debe dar un tick cada 1s.
        if (!tick_dado)
            tick();
    }
    else {
        tick_dado = false;
    }

    if (/* Se presionó el botón de minutos */)
        pasar_un_minuto();

    if (/* Se presionó el botón de horas */)
        pasar_una_hora();

    // Mostrar en pantalla
}
```

Seguramente tengas que hacerle modificaciones. También habría que ver qué sucede cuando `millis()` excede la capacidad de `unsigned long`.

Otra posibilidad más precisa es configurar un Timer de 16 bits para que se ejecute cada 1 segundo y haga pasar el tiempo. Puedes hacerlo con librerías o modificando manualmente los registros del microcontrolador. Si tu caso es el último, deberás consultar la datasheet. Dale clic a los links para ver la del [ATmega328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) y un [tutorial](https://proyectosconarduino.com/curso/interrupciones-arduino-attachinterrupt/?expand_article=1).

Comment: Logre implementar la interrupciones en los botones de una manera distinta, pero ahora enfrento otro problema relacionado a rebotes mecánicos.  Debido a que no puedo utilizar delay, necesito encontrar otra manera de controlar estos rebotes mecánicos y garantizar que el incremento al presionar el botón de solo una  unidad. Segundo, he notado también que el programa desaparece por un momento cada que llega múltiplos de 10.

Comment: He actualizado el código, y la descripción del problema

Comment: @AxwellDuarte creo que no está bien actualizar la pregunta por cada problema que te aparezca. Menos si la edición hace que las respuestas que te dieron ya no respondan la pregunta.

Comment: @AxwellDuarte creo que podrías solucionarlo con un capacitor o dejar de usar la interrupción con los pulsadores y generar un *timer* de forma similar, que cada 100ms por ejemplo, detecte si el botón está presionado. Ya si quieres que sea *más preciso*, puedes verificar que el botón haya sido presionado durante un tiempo/número de ciclos.